# C++ Why the compiler is not able to generate code that returns const reference of a captured variable in Lambda

Tags: c++, lambda

I am watching a talk from Jason Turner about IIFE. There is an example looks like the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#define EOL '\n'
using std::cout;

class C
{
public:
    C(){ std::cout << "Def ctor\n"; }
    C(const C &c){ std::cout << "Copy ctor\n" << EOL; }
    C(C&& c){ std::cout << "Move ctor\n" << EOL; }
    ~C(){ std::cout << "Dtor\n"; }

    void Print() const { cout << "address: " << this << EOL; }
};
int main()
{
    C c;
    c.Print();
    const auto &refc = [&](){ 
        cout << "lambda returns..." << EOL;
        return c; }();
    refc.Print();
    return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
Def ctor
address: 0x7ffe6a6765bf
lambda returns...
Copy ctor
address: 0x7ffe6a6765be
Dtor
Dtor
```

Which shows that the return value is using the copy constructor while the return value is defined as a const reference and creating a newly copied object to return to the const reference.

But if the lambda defined as:

```
const auto &refc = [&]()->const auto&{ 
    cout << "lambda returns..." << EOL;
    return c; }();
```

No copy ctor is invoked and the result is:

```
Def ctor
address: 0x7fff319dc2af
lambda returns...
address: 0x7fff319dc2af
Dtor
```

I think the copy is not necessary, is there a good reason behind the design? And I am wondering that in what situation copying the captured variable is useful?

Comment: My bad, edited, sorry about the confusing

Comment: Lambda returns behave as if declared as `auto`.

Comment: You can return `auto&` if you want to return by reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation on [lambda](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) tells us what is the return type of a lambda if trailing return type is **not** specified:

> Omitted trailing-return-type: the return type of the closure's `operator()` is deduced from return statements *as if for a function whose return type is declared **`auto`***.

So it results in the copy constructor being invoked.

If you want to prevent this, you can use `auto&` or `const auto&` as the trailing return type.

Comment: but the return type of the lambda is `const auto&` instead of `auto`.

Comment: @r0ng: why do you think it is `const auto&`. Do you have any reference for saying that?